# CSS multiple @media (min-width) not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

hopefully a very simple question.

I have three @media (min-width) statements starting at mobile and building up to desktop. For some reason, the third statement doesn't fire.

Example:
    .imgbox {height: 100px; width: 100px;}

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px)  { .imgbox { background-color:red; } } 

@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .imgbox { background-color:green;}
}​

@media (min-width:1001px) {
    .imgbox { background-color:blue;}
}​
```

JS Fiddle to show effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/t5vh316h/ (drag the centre divider to different widths in order to see what I mean)

The box never turns blue, the final query seems to be ignored. Why?!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? Seems there is a missing end bracket for the first media query

Comment: @PIIANTOM, It's there.

Comment: It seems you have a special character colored in red in jsfiddle, following your closing brackets, just delete those and it works.

Comment: Just as a hint: Since you're overwriting all previously set values (background-color) in each media query, you can entirely scratch the max-width assignments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a special character following your existing closing braces as highlighted in your JSFiddle :

[image]

Simply remove those trailing characters as seen below :

```
.imgbox {height: 100px; width: 100px;}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px)  { .imgbox { background-color:red; } } 
@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 1000px) { .imgbox { background-color:green;} }
@media (min-width:1001px) { .imgbox { background-color:blue;} }
```

Which [should resolve the issue](http://jsbin.com/zidubapovo/1/edit?css,output) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you - how bizarre. I blame net2ftp.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was unecessary `dots` after your media queries. I've updated your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/t5vh316h/4/

```
.imgbox {height: 100px; width: 100px;}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px)  { 
   .imgbox { background-color:red; } 
}   

@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .imgbox { background-color:green;}
}

@media (min-width:1001px) {
    .imgbox { background-color:blue;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you had some garbage unicode character #8203, after removing it, your fiddle worked.

https://jsfiddle.net/t5vh316h/5/

```
@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .imgbox { background-color:green;}
}​&#8203;
```